# interfaces, generics and refactoring

Tags: java, generics, refactoring

That awkward moment when you realize you don't know Java...

Got classes A, B, and C. They all extend class X, which defines a UUID id, getId() and setId()

(side note - X and its relationship with A, B, C and D, are fixed, not open to change)

After writing identical methods

```
findA(UUID id, List<A> as)
findB(UUID id, List<B> bs)
findC(UUID id, List<C> cs)
```

, all of which just return an A (B, C) with the matching id, I got the feeling I need to do a little refactoring.

Naively, I thought - oh I know, I will make A, B and C implement an interface, call it `Identifiable`, with `UUID getId()`, use, *mutatus mutandis*, the code from `findA`, and call it a day - `findIdentifiable(UUID id, List<Identifiable> list)` will do the trick(s).

Well, no; findIdentifiable can't be called on a `List<A>` (or `<B>`, or `<C>`). Ouch! Somewhat embarrassing, I didn't see that coming - worse, I don't even understand why it doesn't compile.

That's the first problem. The second problem is - what's a best way to do this refactoring? Because there are more classes on the way, and I don't want to write another identical method...

I am thinking "Generics", but, apparently, despite using generics in simple cases, I'm not sure how to approach this case.

Comment: For starters, you'll probably need a `List<? extends Identifiable>`; you can't subclass generic parameters (a `List<A>` isn't a `List<Identifiable>`).

Comment: thank you! Can't subclass generic parameters...that takes care of the cause of embarrassment =)

Comment: Since A, B and C already extend X, and Identifiable is an interface, I suppose you meant `List<? implements Identifiable>`

Comment: No, `List<? extends Identifiable>`. It's a Generics thing; you use `extends` for interfaces as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the method to return the same type as the type of the list,you need to *type* the method:

```
public <T extends Identifiable> T find(UUID id, List<T> items) {
    for (T item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(id))
            return item;
    }
    return null;
}
```

With this signature, the following call would compile without warnings:

```
List<A> aList;
A found = find(id, aList);
```

Comment: thank you; I've accepted the other answer, but this also works!

Comment: FYI the two answers are very different. The other answer is not a typed method and would not allow the final line of my answer to be coded.

Comment: ooooh, now I get the difference! Indeed, I was just little worried when, in my code, I had to explicitly say `X found = find(id, aList);` -- but this way, I can leave it as A, not having to use X. Kudos!

Comment: @alex  FYI, if you ever change your mind on which answer you want to "accept", you can un-tick an accepted answer and tick a different one.

Comment: done; I do like your answer more, because of parametrization on the return type

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is:

```
Identifiable findIdentifiable(UUID id, List<? extends Identifiable> list) {
    for (Identifiable ident : list) {
        if (ident.getId().equals(id))
            return ident;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Because you can't subclass generic parameters.

But, as you already have `X` which which is extended by `A`, `B` and `C`, why don't you just use `X` instead of `Identifiable` ?

```
X findIdentifiable(UUID id, List<? extends X> list) {
    for (X ident : list) {
        if (ident.getId().equals(id))
            return ident;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved it. Of course, if I knew this generics move, I wouldn't need the interface (by using the interface, I was trying to achieve the same end, except it wasn't possible)